# spliting a string of words into an array of individual words

Tags: php, arrays

I basically have to write a function that takes a string of words from a text box on a form, split the string into the individual words and put them in an array and display the array. The code I have is:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];

function searchterms() {
$split = preg_split("/ /", searchterms());
return $split;
}

echo searchterms($search);
```

I'm getting: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Palindrome\searchterms().php on line 5

As far as I can see it is because I am using searchterms() in the function, but if I move $search into the function and replace searchterms with $search I get a different error.

Edit

The error I get for when I put $search in place of searchterms() in the functions is:
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Palindrome\searchterms().php on line 9
Array

Comment: Q: Are you trying to call "searchterms()" recursively?  Why not substitute this: `$split = preg_split("/ /", $search);`?

Comment: analogous to your question, what does `function a() { echo a(); }` do?  The answer applies here, too.

Comment: Use explode() to get array

Comment: here yes, but I would prefer not to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to split function itself, do:

```
function searchterms($terms) {
    $split = preg_split("/ /", $terms);
    //or
    $split = explode(" ", $terms); //explode by space to make array
    return $split;
}

print_r(searchterms($search));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may Use `explode()` for split string to array.

As Example

```
$strSplitString = "Hello world";
$arraySplitString = explode(" ", $strSplitString);
```

This is how you can split word form string. As the above example

we have split word with space.

Comment: This is simplest way to split sting to array. We can use any character with we want to explode.

Comment: Yes, we can add any character in first parameter, by which we want to split to array